# Select parent google drive folder by id, specify child folder then move a document into the child folder app script

Tags: java, google-apps-script, google-drive-shared-drive

I am trying to create backups of a google sheet to a file and organize it by date. The Parent file will remain constant and I am basing my code on that folder, but the first child folder would need to be the month (in this case June) and then a child folder with the file type name (in this case BackupEX). So I am trying to select the folder by the parent folder ID and iterate through the first and second child folders to paste the backup since the months will keep changing and would necessitate new Id's.

Once the correct file is found I would need it to move the copied file into this folder. But I keep getting TypeError: folders.hasNext is not a function. Any thoughts or better processes to achieve this?

```
var parentFileID = '(obmitted)';
var childFolderName = 'June 2023'
var childFolderName2 = 'BackupEX'

var folders = DriveApp.getFolderById(parentFileID);
while(folders.hasNext()){
  var folder = subFolders.next();

  if(folder.getName() === childFolderName){
    return newFolder.getID();
  }
  if(folder.getName() === childFolderName2){
  return newFolder2.getID();
  }
  DriveApp.getFileById(id).moveTo(newFolder2)
}
```

Comment: getFolderById() does not return an iterator.  So your loop won't work. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getFolderById(String)